# API linking program debug (Yuanta Futures)(Already Fixed~)

Tags: python-3.x, api, anaconda, environment, 32bit-64bit

This is the API linking code (Yuanta Futures)

Our team have tried many weeks, and now it seems to be the last step to complete it.
You can consult he entire codes, packages, files are on my Github.
There is a readme.md at the frontpage of this repository which contains step-by-step process.
(https://github.com/brian09088/Yuanta-API)

When I start to run it on anaconda Spyder, It will pop out GUI window to login
but after few seconds, the it will shows no response, and need to shut down.
Like the picture below:
[image]

```
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None, useBestVisual=False, clearSigInt=True):
        super().__init__(redirect, filename, useBestVisual, clearSigInt)
        self.keepGoing = True
    def MainLoop(self, run_func):

        # Create an event loop and make it active.  If you are
        # only going to temporarily have a nested event loop then
        # you should get a reference to the old one and set it as
        # the active event loop when you are done with this one...
        evtloop = wx.GUIEventLoop()
        old = wx.EventLoop.GetActive()
        wx.EventLoop.SetActive(evtloop)

        # This outer loop determines when to exit the application,
        # for this example we let the main frame reset this flag
        # when it closes.
        while self.keepGoing:
            # At this point in the outer loop you could do
            # whatever you implemented your own MainLoop for.  It
            # should be quick and non-blocking, otherwise your GUI
            # will freeze.

            # call_your_code_here()
            run_func ()
            while not q.empty():
                next_job = q.get()
                DoJob (Bot, next_job)

            # This inner loop will process any GUI events
            # until there are no more waiting.
            while evtloop.Pending():
                evtloop.Dispatch()

            # Send idle events to idle handlers.  You may want to
            # throttle this back a bit somehow so there is not too
            # much CPU time spent in the idle handlers.  For this
            # example, I'll just snooze a little...
            time.sleep(0.10)
            evtloop.ProcessIdle()

        wx.EventLoop.SetActive(old)

def Oninit(self):
    self.keepGoing = True
    return True


def run_job():
    while not q.empty():
        next_job = q.get()
        DoJob(Bot, next_job)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=MyApp()    
    frame = AppFrame(None, title='YuantaQuoteAPI Sample',size = (670,370))
    frame.Show(True)
    Bot = StockBot(frame.Handle)    
    app.MainLoop(run_job)
```

and this py file already done without any error and turn out a GUI login window, but as long as I type my account and pw and now it shows attributeerror: SetMktLogon

> I wonder that any function or package is missing or needs to inherit some objects in it?

**already done and fix the issues, create a 32-bits environment and wxpython for 32-bits also.**
[image: successfully login]

Comment: Shouldn't your `Oninit` be `OnInit` and it should be indented in your `class` definition? You also need to define `keepgoing` in your class. Take a look at [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3#class-variables) to understand `class variables`.

Comment: I just correct **OnInit** type_error , and now it shows ```MainLoop() missing 1 required positional argument: 'keepgoing'``` for the last row
but how to def keepgoing in my class, or need to declare what variables?

Comment: Did you read about the link I sent about [instance variables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3#instance-variables)?

Comment: TKS for giving me some advices and resources to deal with this problem, I finally found that I need to create python-32bits environment and wxPython for also 32-bits , since the financial background is based the past techniques.

Comment: I finally found that I need to create python-32bits environment and wxPython for also 32-bits , since the financial background is based the past techniques.
take a look from my readme.md step-by-step
https://github.com/brian09088/Yuanta-API